# Join and where clause using Criteria in Spring boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to achieve something which is easily doable using named query but i want to do this using criteria.
Below are my two tables.

```
Notification:
id
userId (foreign key to user) 
Notification
Visible

User:
userId,
name,
address
```

No I want to fetch notifications corresponding to a user (user id given) which are visible (value set to 1)

One way to do it to fetch notifications from User and iterate them to see which notification is visible, but i dont want to do that, as that will unnecessarily pull lots of data from db.

What should be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring data jpa to achive this with ease

create an interface extending JPA repository as

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface NotificationRepository extends JpaRepository<Notification,Long (datatype for primary key)> {

List<Notification> findByUseridAndVisible(Long userid,int visible);
}
```

Now you can create service class and directly use this method as

```
class service(){
@Autowired
NotificationRepository notificationrepository;

public void method(){
Long userid=85;
int visible=1;
List<Notification> getnotificationlist= notificationrepository.findByUseridAndVisible(userid,visible);
}
}
```

Hope this will help you .

Comment: i don't have userid in my model, instead i have User object (many to one relation). If i replace userid with user then i get exception "Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Boolean (n/a)]"